# Is there a way to loop mysql (OR statement) to fetch multiple rows in express.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, express

I have a json request in this form:

```
{
"claimNo":["5454545","4554454","45884"]
```

}

the claimNo could hold any number of items(not restricted). I want to get the values and write a query to fetch data from a mysql db where claimNo = the values in the request.
sample response:

```
 "claims": [
    {
        "claimNo": "4554454",
        "ClaimCause": "gjgiukhknl",
        "ClaimAmount": 45550,
    },
    {
        "claimNo": "5454545",
        "ClaimCause": "fdfdfdfdf",
        "ClaimAmount": 0,
    }
]
```

I can successfully loop through the request and display on terminal or even insert into the db with multiple ORs but that only works for a restricted array length.

```
 req.body.claimNo.forEach(element => {
    // console.log(element)

    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM  claims WHERE claimNo = ?'

    connection.query(sql,element,(err, rows, fields) => {
            if(!err){
                // return res.json({
                //     success:true,
                //     errorCode:"",
                //     errorDescription:"",
                //     claims:rows
                // })
                console.log(rows)
            }else
            console.log(err)


    } )
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for a way to query MySQL database for multiple number of `claimNo` entries, and return the result as a single result.

Using MySQL [IN()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php) operator, you can write your query as `select * from claims where claimNo in(?)`

```js
let sql = 'select * from claims where claimNo in(?)';

let claimNos = req.body.claimNo;

connection.query(sql, claimNos, (err, rows, fields) => {
  if(!err){
     // return res.json({
     //     success:true,
     //     errorCode:"",
     //     errorDescription:"",
     //     claims:rows
     // })
     console.log(rows)
 }else
   console.log(err)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to send a separate request for each `claimNo`. You can you the `IN` operator instead. The following should work:

```
const claimsNo = claims.map(claim => claim.claimNo);

const sql = 'SELECT & FROM claims where claimNo IN (?)';
connection.query(sql, [ tableName, claimsNo ], (err, rows, fields) =>{
   ...
});
```